# PUSH_MODE vs PULL_MODE in Specman BFM?

Tags: specman

In which scenario , we would normally go with PUSH_MODE? PULL_MODE interaction is normally recommended one and but I want to know in which scenario or condition we should go with PUSH Mode?

Thanks,

Comment: Likely too localized for this site, but good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it obviates the need to poll the driver instance with `try_next_item()` or `get_next_item()`, which is a win from a performance point of view. (Although calling `driver.get_next_item()` is a blocking call which should suspend any BFM threads waiting for a sequence item.)

Aside from this (probably minor) performance aspect, you might want to reorder sequence items that parallel sequences have specified.  The order of sequence items coming out of the driver is FIFO.  If you have a sequence item that should bypass others for deadlock reasons or you want additional randomization of the order that the items are processed, then you have to manage that yourself by stuffing all the items into your own collection data structure.